# Which content type when uploading *.xlsx files vie gd sdk?

Tags: excel, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a Excel spreadsheet (*.xlsx) to my google drive account via google drive sdk (ruby). I'm using a top level function which does a put request and I'm not sure, which content_type I have to provide. I'm currently using 'application/vnd.ms-excel', which is the known content type for excel files. The response looks like this:

Response code 400 for put https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?v=3&convert=true&upload_id=AEnB2Upn7o44iQmyG3PCM86jrGKW4dK4AngPYsTTv5lsi8l3noa7sOkq1KZjZ0axAX-AF4SOAb6xf3JQbvOVNziapflya5lu3g: http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>GData`InvalidEntryException`The conversion cannot be performed since we do not recognise the file types involved or there is no pathway between them. (GoogleDrive::Error)

It states that they do not know how to convert *.xlsx files to google spreadsheets. But when I can import excel files in spreadsheets via the ui on google.com. Any suggestions?

best regards

Answer (score 2):

Valid mimetype for xlsx file is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. Also if you want to convert that file into Google Spreadsheet format you have to use [the convert flag](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#convert) and set it to true.